# How to check ComboBox.selectedIndexChange event is null or not

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, c#-3.0

How can i check whether ComboBox.SelectIndexchanged Event does not holding any method.

Here i am having methods to Add and Rovemo methods to and from ComboBox which can serve for any comboBox.

```
 public static void AddMethodToComoBox(EventHandler MetodName, ComboBox cbm)
   {
       if(cbm.SelectedIndexChanged==null)
       {
       cm.SelectedIndexChanged += MetodName;
       }

   }
   public static void RemoveMethodToComoBox(EventHandler MetodName, ComboBox cbm)
   {
       if (cbm.SelectedIndexChanged != null)
       {
           cbm.SelectedIndexChanged -= MetodName;
       }

   }
```

If i want to add a method means simply i will call this add method and pass CmoboBox object and Method need to Add similarly to Romove.

But the problem here is if i click a comboBox twice then the method will call twice.
so to avoid that i am checking whether the ComboBox's selectedIndexChanged event is already holding any Mthod. If it is then code will not add the same method again. For that i used the If Condition. but it showing error.
How can i achieve this???

Comment: Fix you logic. Make sure that event registration/deregistration is called exactly once. Your solution, even if it was possible, wouldn't work, because you couldn't connect multiple handlers to the same combo box.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you need to access to the `EventHandlerList` of the `ComboBox`, this event handler list is not exposed publicly, so we have to use a little reflection. The key to get the handler of the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is saved as a field called `EVENT_SELECTEDINDEXCHANGED` in the `ComboBox` class, this field is also non-public, so we also have to use reflection to get it, once got both `EventHanlderList` and the `SelectedIndexChanged` event key, we can check if that key passing in the indexer of `EventHandlerList` returns null or not, returning null means there is not any handler for the event `SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
//Get the field EVENT_SELECTEDINDEXCHANGED
var eventSelectedIndexChangedKey = typeof(ComboBox).GetField("EVENT_SELECTEDINDEXCHANGED", 
                                   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static)
                                  .GetValue(comboBox1);
//Get the event handler list of the comboBox1
var eventList = typeof(ComboBox).GetProperty("Events",
                                 System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                 System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
                                .GetValue(comboBox1, null) as EventHandlerList;
//check if there is not any handler for SelectedIndexChanged
if(eventList[eventSelectedIndexChangedKey] == null){
    //....
} else {
    //....
}
```

However, I feel that your problem is just to avoid adding duplicated (or twice) a handler for the event `SelectedIndexChanged`, so you can always try unregistering the handler first before assigning, it won't never throw exception:

```
public static void AddMethodToComoBox(EventHandler MetodName, ComboBox cbm)
{
   cm.SelectedIndexChanged -= MethodName;
   cm.SelectedIndexChanged += MethodName;
}
public static void RemoveMethodToComoBox(EventHandler MetodName, ComboBox cbm)
{
   cbm.SelectedIndexChanged -= MetodName;//won't never throw exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can check if any handler is attached to the event in the class where it the event is declared. If you try to do a check here you will get something like this:

```
The event SelectedIndexChanged can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=
```

Your best option is to have a dictionary to store the control and the event added for it.